# Arithmetic - linear order of $\mathbb{Z}$-copies

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{M} \equiv (\mathbb{N}, 0, S, <, +)$ and consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined in $M$ by: $a \sim b$ if and only if $d(a, b) < \infty$, i.e. the distance is finite.

It is easy to check that the class $[0^\mathcal{M}]_\sim$ with the restricted operations and the restricted order of $\mathcal{M}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}, 0, S, <, +)$, while for any $a \in \mathcal{M}$ not equivalent to $0^\mathcal{M}$ the corresponding equivalence class $[a]_\sim$ with the restricted operations and order is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}, S, <, +)$, it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-copy.

> Prove that the order $<_\sim$ of the $\mathbb{Z}$-copies of $\mathcal{M}$ is a dense linear ordering without endpoints.

I think that, given some element $a\in M$ in a $\mathbb{Z}$-copy, I need to consider in which copy should $na$ be for $n \geq 2$. But I don't *visualize* this problem well. Any help on how to start this would be appreciated.

Comment: If $a$ is in some $\Bbb Z$-copy, $a+a$ cannot be in the same copy. So there is no maximal, similarly $a/2$ (i.e $k$ such that $k+k\in\{a,a+1\}$) must be in a smaller copy. So there is no minimal either.

Comment: Thanks it helped me start and solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: as suggested by Asaf, the function $f(x) =\lfloor x/2\rfloor$ is definable. For density (and having no initial points), consider $f(x+y) $ (it's approximately the midpoint between $x$ and $y$). For having no largest element, use the function $x\mapsto 2x$, as you have said.

Using the isomorphism you have described, you can assume without loss of generality that $\mathbf N$ is contained in $M$. This should make things easier to visualise.

Comment: Thanks, I had though about $f(x+y)$. However I wander : I see clearly now that because $a$ in not equivalent to $0^\mathcal{M}$, we must have the distance $d(a+a,a)$ infinite, hence $a+a$ is in a distinct $\mathbb{Z}$-copy. However, how can this be formaly proven ? the distance $d(a,b)=k<\infty$ iff $S^k(a)=b$ or $S^k(b)=a$. 

I feel like I only miss one strong argument to prove that $d(a+a,a)=\infty$

Comment: To be torough, I have the complete proof for my question (total order, dense, without endpoint), but it always rely on the fact that $d(a+a,a)<\infty \Rightarrow d(a,0)<\infty$ to conclude a contradiction. And I think I need to refine this

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to prove it properly using successor. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues: I'm happy you have managed. In any event, to prove this it is enough to notice that if $a>n$, then $a+a>a+n$. If $a\not\sim 0$, then $a>n$ for every $n$, so $a+a>a+n$ for every $n$. The successor is not strictly necessary, since it is definable from the rest of the structure, namely $S(a)=a+1$, where $1$ is the smallest nonzero element.

Comment: Assaf? That's the other guy.